# Using Carrierwave with Cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using CarrierWave for images and Amazon Cloudfront as a CDN (without S3).

The issue is that something like: `@user.image_url` returns the non CDN URL, even though i've configured my assets accordingly:

```
  # /config/environments/production.rb
  config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
    if ['jpg','jpeg','png','gif','bmp'].include?(source.split('.').last)
      unless request.ssl?
        "http://cdn.domain.com"
      else
        "https://ge95v2x8h9t3.cloudfront.net"
      end
    end
  }
```

How to make CarrierWave use my `asset_host` proc just like other assets?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure carrierwave to use a custom asset_host (`config.fog_host`... documented in the readme). Although not documented, you can also use a Proc - or anything responding to :call - to determine the string at runtime:

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb#L107

I'm not sure of a way to just point `config.fog_host` directly to Rails' `config.asset_host`, but I'm sure there must be a way to get a reference to it - even if you have to use a non-public interface. Though, I don't know how helpful that would be during development... you likely want assets served from localhost and uploads served from Cloudfront.